# Mongoose query using URI with colons

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to query my MongoDB based on a userID and spotify song's URI, which looks something like this: `spotify:local:A%24AP+Rocky::Goldie:194`. However, it doesn't seem to work. My queries look something like this.

```
app.patch('/api/songs/:spotifyId/:songUri', (req, res) => {
    var id = req.params.spotifyId;
    var uri = req.params.songUri;
    Song.findOne({
        userId: id, 
        uri
    }).then((song) => {
        song.update({$inc: {count:1}}, (e)=>{console.log(e)})
        res.send(song);
    }).catch((e) => {
        res.status(400).send();
    })
})
```

I tried querying using only the userID, which worked, and only the URI, which didn't work. I also created some fake data using a URI that doesn't have colons or percentage signs, which worked. So, I think that my query is not working because of the colons or something.

Does anyone know exactly why the query is not working, and also if there is a way to get my query working using the URI? Or will I have to query using different information?

Answer (score 0):

In that example, it seems that you are specifying that the object's userId should match "id" but don't specify what key you want "uri" to match with (Presumably something like "songUri").

You have:

```
{
    userId: id, 
    uri
}
```

And maybe it should be something more like:

```
{
    userId: id, 
    songUri: uri
}
```

Finally if that doesn't work, maybe try passing in a string for the Uri (surrounding it with quotes) and then parsing it on the backend with JSON.parse()